# How to print "0" and "1" alternatively with only 1 call to printf

Tags: c

This will print alternately "0" and "1":

```
while(1){
    printf("%d", 0);
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d", 1);
    sleep(1);
}
```

To reduce the calls to `printf()` down to only 1 time for each loop, I use XOR:

```
int toggle = 0;
while(1){
   printf("%d", toggle^=1);
   sleep(1);
}
```

I would like to know if there are any other ways to print alternately between 0 and 1 (means toggling the output) with only 1 call to `printf()` (or any other C standard functions) for each loop. And can this achievable without using any variable?

*(user-defined function may not be used)*

Comment: Use `toggle` to change the format.

Comment: What does this question have to do with "taking input with fgets"? I see no call to `fgets` or anything related, nor, for that matter, any attempt to read input.

Comment: Sorry, the title is incorrect. That (old) title is from a draft.

Comment: What's wrong about the current approach?

Comment: There's nothing wrong. I'm just curious about other methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 easy options at least:

```
toggle= !toggle;

toggle = 1 - toggle;
```

and for fun and games that you might not know

```
  toggle = !!!toggle;

  toggle = !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!toggle;
```

Comment: Can these two be put inside `printf()` like this: `printf("%d", (toggle=!toggle))` ?

Comment: yes, in C the assigment operator not only assigns the veriable but also yields an expression that is passed as argument to printf

Answer (score 1):

> And can this achievable without using any variable?

Strictly speaking you obviously need *something* to store the state of your toggle. However, it doesn’t need to be a *variable*.

One alternative would be the use of two functions that recursively call each other:

```
void print_and_wait(int n) {
    printf("%d", n);
    sleep(1);
}

void print_zero(void);

void print_one(void) {
    print_and_wait(1);
    print_zero();
}

void print_zero(void) {
    print_and_wait(0);
    print_one();
}

int main(void) {
    print_zero();
}
```

… but this might violate your “only one call to `printf`” rule, and strictly speaking it *also* uses a variable (the parameter to `print_and_wait`). But it should be clear that you’ll always either need two calls or a variable, since otherwise what do you pass to `printf`?

Comment: that recursive example needs tail recursion optimization enabled when compiling.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson Only if you need an infinite loop. ;-) But in practice this isn’t an issue since all relevant C compilers perform TCO. If you want you could rewrite it with `goto` instead, but then it would become even clearer that this is just OP’s first loop, but un-inlined.

Comment: unfortunately, some compilers do not perform TCO. your code is definitely an infinite loop, and the OP may not understand the subtleties and implications of recursion. i was just pointing out that caveat, for the OP to take note. (please, no goto, that example is awkward enough)

Comment: @AdrienPlisson It’s not infinite if no TCO is performed, because at some point the stack will explode (if it weren’t we wouldn’t need TCO!). Anyway, by “all relevant compilers” I obviously betrayed my desktop/cloud/HPC computing chauvinism: all of GCC, clang, ICC and MSVC perform TCO, and no other compilers are relevant *on the same platforms as these*.

Comment: you obviously never used LabWindows/CVI... anyway, for example, GCC do perform TCO only when called with -O2, -O3, or -Os (or -foptimize-sibling-calls specifically). although that sounds silly, those optimization are not always turned on...